# Is it safe to close file objects passed to subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python

Is it safe to close file objects that have been passed to Popen? For example:

```
import subprocess

fp = open('log.txt', 'w')
args = ...
popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=fp)
fp.close() # <--- Is this OK?
popen.wait()
```

Comment: My guess: it's safe because the child process has its own file descriptor. Calling fp.close() will only close the parent's file descriptor, while the child's (which refers to the same file description) will remain valid.

Comment: Don't think so, why would you do that? Can't you do it after `wait`?

Comment: Why not just use the `with` context manager?

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak child process inherits file descriptors.

Comment: @PauloBu they do, and of course the file descriptors will obviously have the same 'value'. But the namespace of file descriptors is local to a process. You can't possibly accidentally close a file descriptor in *another process*. When the parent closes his file descriptor, that will just decrement the reference count of the file description, leaving behind the child's reference.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak I think you're right. From the `close(2)` man page: _If fd is the last file descriptor referring to the underlying open file description (see open(2)), the resources associated with the open file description are freed_

Comment: @GamesBrainiac This is a simplified version of the code, in the actual version, the popen.wait() happens in a different function, so context manager wouldn't work. I could still manually close the files afterwards, I just want to know if I need to carry around refs to the file objects to close them later.

Comment: @LorinHochstein Note that you can add attributes to `Popen` instances. So you could do: `popen.fp = fp` and after calling the `wait()` method add a `popen.fp.close()`. This just to say that you can pass around the references in an easy way. Sure it isn't elegant. If you want something more elegant you could write a *very simple* subclass that wraps `Popen` and keeps track of the files used.